# Send content to new Google Doc without Authorization/Authentication

Tags: asp.net, google-drive-api, google-docs

Is there a way to send HTML content to a new Google Doc without credentials for authorization/authentication?

In my ASP.NET app, the user creates formatted HTML content using a tinyMCE text editor.  I would like to allow the user to send that content to a new Google Doc via JavaScript function.

Is this possible without knowing the user's Google Drive credentials?

Comment: When you want to make the user create new Google Document and put the HTML content for the user's Google Drive, unfortunately, this cannot be achieved without credentials for authorization/authentication. When you want to make the user create new Google Document and put the HTML content for your Google Drive, this can be achieved using Web Apps. Can I ask you about your situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible without knowing the user's Google Drive credentials?

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately no, this is not possible to do.*

#### More Information:

Creating a Google Doc requires you use the `documents.create` endpoint of the Google Docs API. [As you can see from the documentation page](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create#authorization-scopes), it requires one of the following OAuth scopes:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file

Using these scopes requires a user to log in with their Google account, and as such calling this method without knowing a user's credentials, is not possible.

#### References:

- [Google Docs > API v1 - Method `documents.create`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create)
- [Google Identity Platform - Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)

Comment: Rafa.  What if the user was already Signed In to their Google Drive account?

Comment: They would still need to authenticate the application to access and modify files through the Google Docs API and so being logged into Drive alone isn't enough.